# How to set modal route in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Scenario:
User just attempted a quiz and now is on the result page and upon pressing cross icon, he should be taken back to the main page from where they choose the quiz.In this scenario, they opened dart page, choose the relevant quiz and attempted it, now upon cancel button pressed, user should be taken back to dart page, for this am using modal route, but i know there is some issue with how am implementing it, but dont know exactly how to fix it, let me add my code:

```
IconButton(onPressed: (){
              String mainPageRoute = '/';
              if (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name == DartQuiz1.id) {
                mainPageRoute = DartPage.id;
              }
                else if (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name == DartQuiz2.id) {
                mainPageRoute = DartPage.id;
              } 
               icon: Icon(Icons.cancel)),
```

This code takes me to a blank black screen, i guess because of how am declaring `mainPageRoute` variable, so I have `DartQuiz class` and `DartPage` already stored with their ids in route on `main.dart`, here i just want to access that in `mainPageRoute`, how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

```
    IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
    String mainPageRoute = '/';
    if (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name == DartQuiz1.id ||
        ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name == DartQuiz2.id) {
      mainPageRoute = DartPage.id;
    }
//use push or pushReplacement accroding to yor need 
   // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(mainPageRoute);
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(mainPageRoute);
  },
  icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
)
```